# WordPress - Failing to override woocommerce templates

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, overriding

I am trying to override Woocommerce's templates files by duplicating them in my custom theme directory / woocommerce / templates, but the changes don't appear (I tried simply adding classes to begin with) on the website. Is there something I am doing wrong ?

Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While the directory structure in the WooCommerce plugin itself is:

```
/plugins/woocommerce/templates/
```

You should define it like the following in your theme (note the missing `templates` dir):

```
/yourtheme/woocommerce/
```

In other words, you should put all of the overrides directly within the `woocommerce/` directory (there will be no `templates/` directory). This is definitely confusing.

Comment: I am using the WPLMS theme. It comes with already modified woocommerce files (location : wplms/woocommerce/single-product.php  for example) which work. I tried adding and modifying 'my-account.php' by putting it in the "theme/woocommerce" direction and it didn't work either. I am definitely missing something here. On a side note, it is indeed very confusing.

Comment: I don't understand why you're moving anything. Edit it right where it is...`wplms/woocommerce/single-product.php`. Don't move it...

Comment: I finally found what I was doing wrong. Your answer is right, I was trying to override a file in "/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount" but I was putting it in the wrong path. The correct path is "/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/myaccount". I was putting it in "/mytheme/woocommerce/templates/myaccount", and then I tried in "mytheme/woocommerce/" and neither of them worked. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @rnevius Removing /templates folder in my child theme worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

make a Woocommerce folder inside the theme directory and then follow the folder structure symmetry as in the plugin for the fallback to work properly.

Hope it will work

Comment: Example: To overide the admin order notification, copy: woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php