# Woocommerce template overriding not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I want to override woocommerce templates from my theme. I follow all the steps from the official documents of woocommerce. And I'm sure that there is no woocommerce.php file in my theme. 
So, I can;t understand why it isn't working. 
I'm using twenty seven theme.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've already read this documents
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

> Please Note: When creating woocommerce.php in your theme’s folder, you will
>   be unable to override the woocommerce/archive-product.php custom
>   template in your theme, as woocommerce.php has priority over all other
>   template files. This is intended to prevent display issues.

Also make sure that you don’t have “Template Debug Mode” activated that you can find under:

WP Dashboard -> WooCommerce -> System Status -> Tools

Comment: Yes I've read this documents and I'm sure there is no woocommerce.php file located in my theme directory.

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is no template debug mode activated.

Comment: There's no definitive answer here... this has been marked as accepted but the comments would suggest this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Lee I think he did not understand the answer clearly so he applauded in the following comment that the answer was true but when he understood it correctly.

Comment: Clearing template cache in settings above solved the problem.

Comment: The link to the docs shows you don't use `templates` folder in your themes directory. So this answer is correct?

Answer (score 17):

I had an issue with this relating to the WooCommerce template cache.

The cache can be cleared by navigating to:

WooCommerce > Status > Tools > **Clear template cache**

Comment: I had the correct directory structure so the above answers didn't help me. Clearing template cache finally worked for me. High five!

Comment: After hours of debugging, I found this to be the only working solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Try to declare Woocommerce support in your theme's `function.php`

Comment: Here's how: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/#section-5

Answer (score 7):

After lots of researching, finally I've found my answer from here [WordPress - Failing to override woocommerce templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751082/wordpress-failing-to-override-woocommerce-templates)

Actually, I use all of my files inside the template folder and this is the reason why it didn't work.

So simple steps. But I can't understand how was I miss it!

Thank's  [Mo'men Mohamed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604226/momen-mohamed)   for your suggetions.

Comment: To make it clearer, remove "templates" folder, as in: `your-theme/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php` turns into `your-theme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`

Comment: Yeah this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue. I am using the JupiterX theme with Elementor and trying to override the checkout template in the **JupiterX Child** theme, but it's not loading. I have double checked the path, it's like `themes/jupiterx-child/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`.

**Solution:**

I have resolved the issue. Actually, the JupiterX theme has its own WooCommerce overriding structure, that is `themes/jupiterx/lib/templates/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php` and the same for the child theme that is `themes/jupiterx-child/lib/templates/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`.

**For more details:** [themes.artbees.net/docs/overriding-woocommerce-templates](https://themes.artbees.net/docs/overriding-woocommerce-templates)

Answer (score 1):

Yes i agree with Mobashir. 
There are three steps to check why override not working :

1. Check in functions.php for woocommerce supported added ( URL : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/ )
2. Check spelling of directory and files is proper in theme such as your-theme/woocommerce. ( URL : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ )
3. Woocommerce allow to change the location of woocommerce template. Hook is : **woocommerce_template_path** .If you are using the premium theme then check for filter hook in your theme's functions.php file. If that hook exits then use that location which is mention in that hook's callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

Clear cache, then just swap/activate themes to a wordpress standard theme, then swap back to yours. Happy Days!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, to anyone for whom these solutions didn't work - my issue was that although my child theme (Velux) didn't have a woocommerce.php file in it, my parent theme (Primer) had a woocommerce.php in wp-content/themes/primer/inc/compat. I'm not sure what was in it that was conflicting, but when I replaced it with a blank woocommerce.php file (deleting it gave me a critical error), my overrides started working.