# Why wocommerce email template override not working?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize order emails content. According to woocommerce i need to do this in **Woocommerce** > **Settings** > **Emails** > **Manage**

Here i have the option to **Copy file to theme**. The file copies in
*theme-child/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php*

But woocommerce does not send the customized email template that i have in my child theme.

Also in **View Template** option i can edit template code apparently, but when i **Save Changes** appears **Could not write to template file**.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Check your file permissions

Comment: Files and folders have permissions, but still not working.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848547/woocommerce-template-overriding-not-working and see if it helps.

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have `define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', true );` in your `wp-config.php` file… Or try to add `define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', false );` in your `wp-config.php` file… When the option `WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE` is enabled, it disable templates override through the child theme (or the theme).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. i've alredy configured WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE as false in wp-config.php but still not working.