# How can i refresh the template version data in the Woocommerce Status Report?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I've updated the templates, but the Status Report still shows the versions as outdated, even though they're not...

...how can I refresh the Status Report so it gives the versions the green light?

Thanks!

I've updated the files locally and uploaded to the live server too, but both versions show the warnings in the Status Reports, they do seem to update intermittently, but I'd like to trigger a refresh.

Answer (score 11):

There are two transients in the database (in wp_options table) which are checked to see if a refresh is needed of the template status:

```
_transient_timeout_wc_system_status_theme_info
_transient_wc_system_status_theme_info
```

Delete these two and refresh the status page and it'll update properly.

I used this SQL statement for convenience (change for your table prefix from "wp_" if not using the default):

```
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE('%wc_system_status_theme_info%');
```

You can also check cron isn't disabled in wp-config.php with:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Answer (score -1):

The cache can be cleared by navigating to:

WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Clear template cache

This question is a duplicate to:
[Woocommerce template overriding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848547/woocommerce-template-overriding-not-working)

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with template cache, but the two options in database Phil noted.